# Find out what directory from filesystem Apache hits when a given url is requested

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I find out what directory from a local filesystem Apache web server hits, when a given url is requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) provides the `%f` directive which logs the file that is accessed. This is the full path to the file e.g. accessing

```
http://example.com
```

the `%f` directive might log

/var/www/html/index.html

This seems to work correctly even if there are `alias` and `redirect` directives that can otherwise confuse matters.

You will need to edit your apache config and add `%f` to your `LogFormat` then restart apache.

You can then read the information from the access log.

Comment: It works! I added %f to the LogFormat in my VirtualHost configuration and it included full path to the file. I saw that Apache doesn't hit correct DocumentRoot and this will help me to debug the issue.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in the log file.

It's located at `/var/log/apache2/yourwebsite_access.log`.

Use `tail -f <path_to_log_file>` to check in real time.

Comment: I don't think this works. It shows the request but that doesn't have the path to where the document root is mapped into the filesystem. How do aliases affect this too ?

Comment: As I understand OP, he want's to know which directory in its document root is being accessed when someone click an url. Maybe I missunderstood something?

Comment: Which document root, there could easily be many.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually I have an issue with document root, and I want to know exactly which document root is applied for my request. I've checked the log, but it shows only subdirectory of the current document root, which I try to find out.